# digit to integer in same order C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function called `fun(int num, int * array);` which takes an `int` and `int array` as its arugments. I'm trying to convert `int` to the array.

When i run the program i don't get the array displayed properly

```
int fun(int num, int*array) {
   int count =0;
   while(num>0) {
      num/= 10;
      count++;
   }
   array[count];
   // for loop works
 }
```

When i print the array in the program i.e. everytime I run the program i get random digits.

Comment: algorithmically, it seem correct.
Can we have a minimal compilable source code which reproduce your problem ?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you are basically trying to convert a raw binary number to [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: No, he want to "explode" his integer into an array of digit.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] as well as: 1. the output you get. 2. the output you want.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are trying to do. How does your number transform into an array, and how does that array transform into a single integer to be printf()ed?

Comment: You are passing a `NULL` pointer to `func` and there you access it. There is now way that this could end well....

Answer (score 1):

What this line is supposed to do ?

```
array[count];
```

Since your integer array will change in your fun function, you have to allocate the memory (by using malloc, realloc, ...).

edit : plus, you already change the value hold by "num" when you count how many digit there are in "num".
Make a copy of "num" !

edit 2 : the more i look your function, the more it seem you will have problem using it.

Fisrt, you want to explode your integer into an array of int.
Okay, but integer have range, thus meaning integer have a maximum digit.
From my memories, there are 20 digit in an 64bit integer.
So you can simply use "int array[NB_DIGIT_INT_MAX];" with "#define NB_DIGIT_INT_MAX 21".
So, allocating is not necessary AND add complexity in your code (the caller will have to free after the function call).

Second, your fun function doesn't say how many case will hold your integer.
Let's say num = 12, your array will have "array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2", but how do you know where to stop ?
If num = 2345, how do you know that only the 4 first case in your array is legit ?
There are 2 way : You have an another variable that hold the actual size of the array, or you have a special value in your array that say "it's the end" (like '\0' for char array used as string).

You can use "-1".

Let's give a try, and don't hesitate to ask question if thing are unclear (english is not my motherlanguage)

Comment: int *array = malloc(count * sizeof(int)) ?

Comment: Carrefull, it seem you declare again the variable "array".
You have to send the address of your pointer, in order to change your pointer from within "fun" function.
Prototype = "int fun(int num, int *(*array))", malloc = "(*array) = malloc(count * sizeof(*(*array))) "

Comment: *Since your integer array will change in your fun function,..* Could you please explain what you exactly mean??

Comment: Alright, when i do *array = malloc(count *sizeof(*(*array))); i get error

Comment: @Prins `*array = malloc(count *sizeof(*(*array)));` --> `*array = malloc(count *sizeof(int));`. Btw what do you think `sizeof(*(*array))` does exactly?

Comment: I mean that since "array" will be allocated in the function, you need to have the address of the address. If not, only the "array" variable in the fun function will have the value of the memory bloc allocated, and the array int the main function will be inchanged.

Comment: sizeof (*(*array)) will get the sizeof of **array.
Previously, I said that you need to give the address of the integer array.
So you need to have "int **array" in the parameter of the fun function. So sizeof(**array) will be like sizeof(int), at the exception that if you want to have another type for the "array" variable, sizeof(**array) will be correct be sizeof(int) willbe not.

Comment: ?? You shouldn't, unless array's type is "int *". It must be "int **".
Prototype = "int fun(int num, int **array)", array = "int *array = NULL;", usage = "fun(12345, &array);"

Comment: arrays type it int*

Comment: Do you know how memory allocation with array througth function call work ?
if you have "int fun(int num, int *array)", this will NEVER work.
Exactly the same as "int fun2(int var)" : the "var" variable will not be changed after a call to fun2 function.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not even allocated, this can not work as expected. You are even lucky not to have a segmentation fault. If you want to add an integer to an array making it grow, you need to allocate a larger array, copy the values and add the new one to the new array and delete the previous array, keeping `array` variable as a pointer to the new array. Moreover, you need to pass the size of the actual array as an argument of `fun`.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` variable can be global, Initialize it outside all functions like this

```
short count;
```

The whole program could be modified like below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
short count;
void fun(int num, int **ptr) {
// You need a pointer to a pointer and return type can be void
 int num_copy=num;
 count=0; // Setting the count to zero
 while(num_copy>0) {
  num_copy/= 10; // Don't modify the original number
  count++;
 }
//Allocate enough memory to store the digits
 *ptr=malloc(count*sizeof **ptr);
 if(NULL==*ptr){
  perror("Can't allocate memory");
  exit(1);
 }
// Then do the loop part with original num
 for(int i=count -1; i>=0; i--) {
  (*ptr)[i] = num%10;
  num /= 10;
 }
// By now you have an array 'array' of integers which you could print in main.
}

int main()
{
int number = 123456789;
int *array;
fun(number,&array); // &array is of type pointer to a pointer to integers
 //Now print the individual digits
printf("Individual digits are : \n");
for(int i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
 printf("%d\n",array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are converting from an integer to digits. But I don't see where your code writes anything to the array.

If the array wasn't initialized before this, that would explain why it still contains random values.